# Paid lounge access at Istanbul Ataturk airport

Tags: layovers, istanbul, lounges, isl

So I missed my flight and I now have a 23 hour layover at Istanbul Ataturk airport. Is there any lounge I can pay for access to - preferably airside?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [primeclass CIP](http://www.primeclass.com.tr/en/index.htm) Lounge allows paid access for what appears to be 30 Euro. Access is also available via PriorityPass.  It's a long time since I've been in that specific lounge, but I seem to remember that it was one of the nicer airport lounges I've visited.

There is also a hotel which offers both airside and landside rooms.  If you have the ability to go landside you'll find that the rooms are significantly cheaper!

There is also a [HSBC lounge](http://www.hsbcpremier.com/1/2/hsbcpremier/airport-lounges) which you can access for free if you have a HSBC credit card of any type.

Comment: Both of these are correct, except that for the HSBC lounge you need to have one of their 'premiere' cards to get in for free; classic / Gold account holders need to pay 50 Turkish lira.